# Conditional breakpoints for Xdebug in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

Let us suppose we have these 2 methods:

```
function superFunction($superhero,array $clothes){
    if($superhero===CHUCK_NORRIS){
      wear($clothes);
    } else if($superhero===SUPERMAN) {
      wear($clothes[1]);
    }
}

function wear(array $clothes)
{
   for($piece in $clothes){
       echo "Wearing piece";
   }
}
```

So what I want to achieve is to put a breakpoint in PhpStorm into function `wear` but I want to get fired only when `$superhero` variable has the value `CHUCK_NORRIS` how I can do that. Imagine that the function `superFunction` is getting called over a zillion times and pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> all over the time is kind of counter productive.

Comment: Put the break point on the function call (inside the if statement) and step into the function..

Comment: ...or pass the $superhero value as parameter to the wear function and add a condition on the break point to stop execution only if the $superhero parameter is CHUCK_NORRIS

Comment: *"is to put a breakpoint  into function `wear` but I want to get fired only when `$superhero` variable has the value "* -- not going to work as `$superhero` is outside of the function scope. You have to do what @MateiMihai have said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've already commented, there are at least 2 possible ways to achieve that:

1. Put the break point on the function call (inside the if statement) and step into the function

   ```
   function superFunction($superhero, array $clothes)
   {
       if ($superhero === CHUCK_NORRIS){
           wear($clothes); // <---- put the break point on this line
       } elseif ($superhero === SUPERMAN) {
           wear($clothes[1]);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Pass the `$superhero` value as parameter to the `wear` function and add a condition on the break point to stop execution only if the `$superhero`'s value is `CHUCK_NORRIS`

into the function

```
    function superFunction($superhero,array $clothes)
    {
        if ($superhero === CHUCK_NORRIS) {
            wear($clothes, $superhero); // <---- passing the $superhero variable
        } elseif ($superhero === SUPERMAN) {
            wear($clothes[1]);
        }
    }

    function wear(array $clothes, $superhero = null)
    {
        for ($piece in $clothes) { // <---- conditional break point here: $superhero === CHUCK_NORRIS
            echo "Wearing piece";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Put the breakpoint in PhpStorm as usual then right-click on the red disc that marks the breakpoint in the editor's gutter. In the popup window that opens enter the condition when you want your breakpoint to stop the execution of the script. Any condition that is valid in the code where you put the breakpoint can be input here.

For example, enter `$superhero===CHUCK_NORRIS`.

Press the "Done" button and you're good to go. Debug the script as usual. The debugger evaluates the condition everytime the breakpoint is hit but it stops the script only when the condition is evaluated to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set PHPStorm to break only if another breakpoint was hit previously.

```php
    function superFunction($superhero,array $clothes){
        if($superhero===CHUCK_NORRIS){
          wear($clothes); // breakpoint here
        } else if($superhero===SUPERMAN) {
          wear($clothes[1]);
        }
    }
    
    function wear(array $clothes)
    {
       for($piece in $clothes){ // breakpoint here
           echo "Wearing piece";
       }
    }
```

Right click on the second breakpoint and click More

[image: right click on a breakpoint dialog box]

Then select the first breakpoint under "Disable until hitting the following breakpoint"
[image]